# Ask for higher permission using twitter oauth2

Tags: twitter, oauth, oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth

I'm using twitter oauth2 for signin. Inside the app there is an optional feature that requires write-permission. Asking the user for write permissions when they try to "sign in using twitter" isn't optimal, so how can I ask for higher permissions when I actually need them?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to reauthenticate the user e.g. start again at https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/reference/post/oauth/request_token and specify *x_auth_access_type* as *write*